# Multi-way nonparametric anova

Tags: r, anova, nonparametric

I have to analyze a factorial design with five factors (one of them nested in another one) and numeric responses. I would like to perform a nonparametric ANOVA, but of course I can't use neither Kruskall Wallis nor Friedman test (I have replicated measures). Is there a command or a code in R that could help me?
Thank you!
Stefania

Comment: What is the reason for a non-parametric approach?

Comment: @chl The reason why I need a non-parametric approach is that my responses don't satisfy the hypothesis of the model ANOVA (non gaussian residuals, heteroskedasticity, strange dispersion of residuals versus fits) and no transformation is useful (i've  also tried tried with a Box-Cox transformation with bad results).
Thank you everybody for the answers!!!
-- Stefania Oct 16 '10 at 7:49

Answer (score 4):

Tukey's Median Polish is implemented in R as medpolish {stats}.  See Chapter 6 in [Venables and Ripley](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS4/VR4stat.pdf)

Comment: I seem to remember that Median Polish can be used for a two-way layout; how does it extend to 5 factors, including nesting?

Comment: @chl Median polish can work with as many factors as you might care to handle.  Tukey does some three-way examples (by hand!).

Answer (score 4):

The [vegan](http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan.html) package implements permutation testing for distance based ANOVA, which should work with multi-way, repeated measures data.

Comment: do you have a function command for doing that?

Comment: @EDi Lookup `adonis` in the on-line help for vegan. (And [Jari Oksanen](http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan.html) for more info on the package itself.) BTW, this is a pretty elegant answer, you can vote it up like I did a long ago :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might check out the ezBoot() function in the ez package for bootstrapping confidence intervals on your effects of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Pierre Legendre has some Code on his homepage:
[nest.anova.perm.R (D. Borcard and P. Legendre): Nested anova with permutation tests (main factor and one nested factor, balanced design).](http://www.bio.umontreal.ca/legendre/indexEn.html)